# Can a Console Application eventually run out of memory just by writing lots of Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, console-application

Does anybody know?

For a heavy duty test I wrote a console application that I hope will run, problem free, for days. At least.
This Console application will be writing lots of `Console.WriteLine` (about a line every 150 msec) to the console.

Do I have to worry about my memory at some point? Because consoles keep all text in memory.
Or does Windows take care of what's written to the console somehow?

Comment: `Do I have to worry about my memory at some point?` Why don't you try it? write an infinite loop that outputs something..... It would be faster than waiting an answer here....

Comment: @L.B. Sure. That's what I've been doing the last few hours. I'm just curious if I have to worry about memory in the long run. 
If so, I'll rewrite it a bit to output it to a text file.

Comment: This likely depends on the console and OS. I've run simulations for hours that print repeatedly, and never run into an issue. Expect it to continue consuming memory, but on most modern computers, I doubt this will be a problem. Open the task manager, find the process, and watch it's memory usage. If the output is constant, that should give you a good idea. Openness resource monitor to get a graph of the usage.

Comment: It doesn't keep all console output. No it won't run out of memory. You should pull down the window menu at the top left and have a look at `Defaults` and `Properties` dialogs. In there you set the limit on scrollback history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the properties, under Layout is a Screen Buffer Size that is set default to 9000 lines. That's all I needed to know.

Thanks @doug65536!